# Apache mod_rewrite for a specific domain under same directory

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, yii

I have wrote a website using PHP & Yii Framework, and there I have my `.htaccess` file which has this `mod_rewrite` statement to use clean URL's:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

For example I use this domain: `www.example.com` & `popstan.net`, and URL rewriting for these domains works **like in a dream!**

However, I'm now creating a blog, and with my Yii controllers I have this structure for accessing blog articles, blog categories and single blog article:

- http://example.com/blog/ - lists all new articles
- http://example.com/blog/category/some-category - list articles from specific category
- http://example.com/blog/article/some-alias-path - previews a single blog article

Now, I wish to use this blog, but under domain: `http://blog.example.com/`, and to maintain those URL structures, and I wish not to copy my website on two separate directoryies (ie. blog directory).

Is it possible to use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite URL's for a domain, but to have the URL's be fetched from a parent directory?

Comment: this [link][1] will help you. its about apache virtual hosts...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496760/dynamic-subdomains-defined-subdomains-via-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You should simply :

1) create a `blog.example.com` [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/examples.html) that points to the same directory,

2) define corresponding url rules in Yii config, e.g. :

```
'http://blog.example.com/<action:\w+>/<param:\w+>'=>'/blog/<action>',
'http://blog.example.com/'=>'/blog/index',
```

You don't need to modify your `.htaccess`.